# How can I add an editable ComboBox to Vista's Common Item Dialog?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-vista, combobox

Vista introduced the new [Common Item Dialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913.aspx) for opening and saving files that supersede the old Common File Dialogs. Custom controls can be added by utilizing the simple [IFileDialogCustomize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775912(VS.85).aspx) interface. One of them is a standard `ComboBox` which is non-editable. Is there any way to create an editable `ComboBox` or modify an existing one (by adding the `CBS_DROPDOWN` style)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. There is no guarantee that the controls you add with `IFileDialogCustomize` are Win32 controls. (And in fact, I believe they aren't.) Since they aren't Win32 control, there's nothing to set the `CBS_DROPDOWN` style on. Sorry.